# How filter out the element that are greate than the average using Stream IPA?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I need to extract a list of values from the source collection of integers that are greater than the arithmetic mean.

I want to know whether it is possible to do without using 2 streams?

*I want to achieve this using the methods of the `Collectors` class.*

```
        double average = values.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingInt(Integer::intValue));
        List<Integer> integers = values.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(integer -> integer > average))
            .get(true);
```

Comment: I'd just calculate the average once, not re-calculating it for every single element like you're doing.

Comment: but in one stream, using the methods of the Collect class it is impossible to do?

Comment: It needs two passes: one to calculate the average, one to partition based on that.

Comment: Previously posted as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71138165/compute-average-and-values-higher-than-average-in-single-iteration#71138165, with answers, but deleted

Answer (score 1):

> it is possible to do without using 2 streams

No, it contradicts the definition of the arithmetic mean. You have to process all elements in the stream in order to find it.

But instead of recalculating the average value for every element, it's more **performance-wise** to start with finding the average and then just filter out the elements that are greater.

Note, that `Collectors.partitioningBy()` produces a map that **isn't used** somehow in your code. It's unnecessary to allocate this intermediate data structure in memory in order to extract a list from it. If you need a list, then collect values directly to the list.

```
        List<Integer> source = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

        double average = source.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingInt(Integer::intValue));

        List<Integer> greaterThenAverage = source.stream()
                .filter(i -> i > average)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(greaterThenAverage);
```

**output**

```
[4, 5]
```

Comment: @GoodYork If you still wonder *it is possible to do without using 2 streams* - then the answer is no, it contradicts the definition of the arithmetic mean. You have to process all elements in order to find it. And then you need a second iteration to filter out the element that are greater then the mean.